# Given a folder path in Colab, how can I extract a specific portion of that in python?

Tags: python, file, directory, path

For an example, I have my folder path as **"/content/data/a/b/c/d/"**
How can I extract the "b" from this path?

Comment: Identified how? Identified as the fourth section?

Comment: If you are fine using [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) you can use [`Path.parents`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parents) to get a sequence of the ancestors, which you can filter to get the directory you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "b" never moves

```
file_path = "/content/data/a/b/c/d/"
file_path.split('/')[4]
```

If it does move

```
file_path = "/content/data/a/b/c/d/"
file_path[file_path.index("b")]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> file_path = "/content/data/a/b/c/d/"
>>> p = Path(file_path).parts
>>> p
('\\', 'content', 'data', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
>>> b = p[4]
>>> b
'b'
```